# jQuery inArray is always returning -1

Tags: jquery

I cannot figure out why I keep getting -1 for lastProductIndex when clearly the lastProductID is in the array!

```
var lastProductID = 6758;
var allProductIDs = [5410, 8362, 6638, 6758, 7795, 5775, 1004, 1008, 1013]
var lastProductIndex = $.inArray(lastProductID, allProductIDs);
```

Comment: you posted a questions about this only a few minutes ago..which included two code samples..

Comment: What does `allProductIDs.indexOf(lastProductID)` return?

Comment: yea, and that's pertaining to something totally different.  Why I was getting -1 for indexOf.  You suggested to use inArray.  So this is a separate issue becuase I cannot figure out why when using inArray I get -1.  So this is why I seprated it out and also so I can show code here as if I replied with code in a comment it looks like sh** and is unformatted!  So this is not really the same issue!

Comment: -1, and that was my first problem in another post.  You can't supposedly use indexOf on an integer array.

Comment: @coffee: you can, just not on IE.

Comment: @coffeeaddict: I just to meant to run this as a diagnostic in Firebug, not as a replacement to $.inArray in production code.

Comment: I am told you CAN use indexOf on arrays with numbers

Comment: >>I just to meant to run this as a diagnostic in Firebug (I am not getting you here, what is that?  I use firebug but what are you referring to, just the jscript debugger?)

Comment: Here is why everyone hates languages that are not TYPED.  I had initially set the lastProductIndex value with a value, but it was a string (because I had gotten the value from an HttpResponse object from returned JSON.  So consequently I had set the variable to a string because of the returned JSON value was a string.  When I hard coded the number 6758 into $.inArray it worked fine so that caught my attention.

Answer (score 45):

I had the same problem yesterday,,

```
var data=[2,4,6,8];
alert( $.inArray(4,data) ) // output 1 as expected
alert( $.inArray("4",data) ) // output -1 as expected
```

Generally this occurs when you get the value to check from a input element or something that returns a string. You need to do `parseInt(string,radix)` to convert it to a number...

Comment: i have the same problem and this solved it to me .. thanks iim

Comment: Thanks mate, this helped me. It seems that 4 was a string for me.

Comment: var data=["2","4"];
$.inArray(String(4),data);
if you have a haystack of strings (array) and a needle as int. String()

Answer (score 9):

Try this instead:

```
$.grep(allProductIDs, function(n) { return n == lastProductID; });
```

Caveat:  grep returns an array.

It looks like jQuery does an === instead of == with inArray.

Comment: I am not familiar with === or this technique.  So you pass in the param on the left into the function as n .  Then return n and it does some sort of lookup for lastProductID?

Comment: yea, an array isn't what I want returned.  Nice function though.  I resolved my problem, see above.

Comment: This worked better for me than the @iim.hlk's answer because my "lastProductID" could be an alphabetic string.

Comment: +1, Wow.. thanks... Its really awesome... It is also working with date calculations.

Answer (score 6):

Here is why everyone hates languages that are not TYPED. I had initially set the lastProductIndex value with a value, but it was a string (because I had gotten the value from an HttpResponse object from returned JSON. So consequently I had set the variable to a string because of the returned JSON value was a string. When I hard coded the number 6758 into $.inArray it worked fine so that caught my attention.

Comment: You might as well give yourself the correct answer. You've earned it. :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209329/stackoverflow-should-i-answer-my-own-question-or-not

Comment: Of course if it was a strongly typed language, your code wouldn't compile.

Comment: to be honest, that's what can happen when you use a variable for more than one purpose (and on top, more than one data type)  :)

Comment: If I have a strongly typed language, I can rely on the datatype. If in JavaScript utilizing jQuery I call `val()` on an input field I would not want to rely on the type. To my surprise mostly string although I require numeric.

Answer (score 3):

> The `$.inArray()` method is similar to JavaScript's native `.indexOf()`
>   method in that it returns -1 when it doesn't find a match. If the
>   first element within the array matches `value`, `$.inArray()` returns 0.

According to:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any other JavaScript libraries in your page?

There could be a conflict for the `$` shorthand if you are. This can be solved in a number of ways, one of which would be wrapping the code in a self-executing anonymous function

```
(function($) {
    var lastProductIndex = $.inArray(lastProductID, allProductIDs);
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I am using a mix of standard JavaScript and also some jQuery.  I'm using some functions of JCarousel

Comment: >>There could be a conflict for the $ shorthand if you are.

not the issue...I had this same problem even when I was using indexOf

Comment: Using that self-executing anonymous function inside my existing function ended up hiding the lastProductIndex variable so I ended up with an error saying lastProductIndex variable did not exist on the lines after this that were trying to reference it

Comment: You would need to declare lastProductIndex outside of the function and assign it a value inside.

Answer (score -1):

This confused me too at first, I had an identical problem. It seems jQuery.inArray() requires a string. So you could just do:

> var lastProductID = "6758";

In my case I was trying to do:

> var foo = date.getTime()/1000;

Which always resulted in -1 being returned from $.inArray()

But you can just cast it to a string:

> var foo = String(date.getTime()/1000);

Hope that helps somebody :)

Comment: $.inArray does not require a string. The OPs code works fine - http://jsbin.com/uqiba .

Comment: Check the source of $.inArray - it just runs through and does === comparisons. Strings unrelated, unless you're trying to compare 4 to '4'.