# inArray returns -1 in each loop with stirngs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two arrays containing string values (newValues and oldValues). I iterate over the oldValues array with jquery each and check the value against the newValues array. However even if the value exists in the newValues array, it is only found if I do a toString first. IE Debugger Console howerver says, that this is already a string (and thats what I expect too).

Code:

```
$(oldValues).each(function () {
   // always fails (debug snapshot taken here)
   if (jQuery.inArray(this, newValues) === -1) { 
      // ...
   }
});
```

[image: IE F12 Debugger Console]

Why do I have to do a toString first, even when *this* is already of type string? Has this something to do with the jquery each?

All similar questions I've found had to do with type mismatch, but this isn't the case here, right?

Comment: there is already a similar thread here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071441/jquery-inarray-is-always-returning-1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071441/jquery-inarray-is-always-returning-1) -1 = FALSE
else it's TRUE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following code instead:

```
$(oldValues).each(function (index, value) {
   if (jQuery.inArray(value, newValues) === -1) {
```

Unless you use [`"use strict";`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode), the primitive string is boxed in a `String` object (see it yourself: `typeof this` is `"object"`, rather than string). Consequently, the search method (the `indexOf` method of an array) does not find the value.
The above code solves this problem by correctly utilising [`jQuery().each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).